# Find all radiuses of convergence for this series - is my approach correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

> I'm supposed to find all radiuses of convergence for this power
>   series:
>
> $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^{2}}{3^{k}}x^{k}$

I've worked with ratio test: $\frac{{}\frac{(k+1)^{2}}{3^{k+1}}}{\frac{k^{2}}{3^{k}}}$

This equals: $\frac{(k+1)^{2}*3^{k}}{3^{k+1}*k^{2}} =$

= $\frac{(k+1)^{2}}{3k^{2}} =$

= $\frac{1}{3}\left ( \frac{k+1}{k} \right )^{2} =$

= $\frac{1}{3} \left ( 1+\frac{1}{k} \right )^{2} =$

= $\frac{1}{3} \left ( 1+0 \right )^{2} = \frac{1}{3}$

$
\Rightarrow R = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}} = 3$

Which means that 3 is the convergence radius.

Is everything correct? What confused me is we were supposed to find radius**es** but I have only found one.

How can I find them all?

Comment: "Radiuses"? What do you think there are several?

Comment: As I said I'm confused. For this series I don't know but I'd like to know in general how it's done, how to find several / all radiuses of a series.
Also like to know if my approach is correct pls :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly using Cauchy-Hadamard formula with the $\;n\,$ th root:

$$\sqrt[k]{\frac{k^2}{3^k}}=\frac{\sqrt[k]{k^2}}3\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\frac13$$

and thus the radius of convergence is $\;R=3\;$...so you were right! (Though your use of equality signs isn't very careful...). But there is only one for *each* power series, not several.

Comment: Thank you!
So a power series cannot have more than ONE convergence radius?

Comment: @kathelk Indeed so. Now, several series around several points can have several radius of convergence, but once you fixed one power series that's it: one single radius of convergence.

Comment: @kathelk: A radius of convergence is defined by a $\limsup$, and the $\limsup$ of a sequence is unique.